# S3 Implementation for org.apache.parquet.io.InputFile?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, parquet

I am trying to write a Scala-based AWS Lambda to read Snappy compressed Parquet files based in S3.  The process will write them backout in partitioned JSON files.

I have been trying to use the org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader class to read the files... the non-deprecated way to do this appears to pass it a implementation of the org.apache.parquet.io.InputFile interface.  There is one for Hadoop (HadoopInputFile)... but I cannot find one for S3.  I also tried some of the deprecated ways for this class, but could not get them to work with S3 either.

Any solution to this dilemma?

Just in case anyone is interested... why I am doing this in Scala?   Well... I cannot figure out another way to do it.  The Python implementations for Parquet (pyarrow and fastparquet) both seem to struggle with complicated list/struct based schemas.

Also, I have seen some AvroParquetReader based code ([Read parquet data from AWS s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831273/read-parquet-data-from-aws-s3-bucket)) that might be a different solution, but I could not get these to work without a known schema. but maybe I am missing something there.

I'd really like to get the ParquetFileReader class to work, as it seem clean.

Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop uses its own filesystem abstraction layer, which has an implementation for s3 (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#S3A).

The setup should look someting like the following (java, but same should work with scala):

```java
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set(Constants.ENDPOINT, "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/");
conf.set(Constants.AWS_CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER,
    DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.class.getName());
// maybe additional configuration properties depending on the credential provider


URI uri = URI.create("s3a://bucketname/path");
org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path path = new Path(uri);

ParquetFileReader pfr = ParquetFileReader.open(HadoopInputFile.fromPath(path, conf))
```

Comment: Was not working for me earlier... can't remember why.. will go back and try it again.. thanks.

Comment: stick a stack trace up. if the lamba executes within an IAM role where the credentials for AWS access are served up on a 169.x server the way they are for EC2 VMS, then the org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider is the cred provider needed -which is on the default auth chain anyway

Comment: Do we have anything similar for google cloud storage?